# How can I utilize Java multi-threading for maximum speed and minimum errors?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing a homework assignment and I've been having trouble utilizing threads to make the program run as fast as possible. The assignment is about generating a ton of random self-avoiding walks (SAW's).

The guidelines for the assignment said to execute 1,000 threads that will run concurrently and thus save as much time as possible. Within each thread, a nested for loop exists. For n = 10 up to n = 40, the program generates N_w walks. My goal is to make N_w as large a number as possible and generate more walks.

I've created 1,000 threads, but I'm not sure if I'm correctly utilizing them to calculate as fast as possible.

SawGenerator is a class that extends Thread and contains a nested for loop to generate all the walks.  I tried generating 1,000 threads by creating 1,000 SawGenerators and starting them one after the next, with the N_w in every SawGenerator set to 500.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        SawGenerator mySawGenerator = new SawGenerator();
        mySawGenerator.start();
}

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry : numSuccessfulWalks.entrySet()) {
        int curLength = entry.getKey();
        System.out.println("SAW's of length:  " + curLength);
        System.out.println("    numSuccessfulWalks(" + curLength + "): " + numSuccessfulWalks.get(curLength));
        System.out.println("    <Rn^2>: " + totalEndSqDist.get(curLength)/numSuccessfulWalks.get(curLength));
        System.out.println("    Fraction Perimeter: " + numSuccessfulWalks.get(curLength)/(1000*500));
    }

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Total Runtime in Seconds: " + ((endTime-startTime) / 1000));
```

However, this gave me several different outcomes:

1) My program would often crash with a ConcurrentModificationException. I believe this is because my thread involves insertions into Hashmaps, and the error was the result of multiple threads trying to alter the same Hashmap at the same time.

2) The "Total Runtime in Seconds", AKA the last line of my code, would be printed without the Map information that I also wanted to print preceding it. There would be no error output, and I'm not sure what causes this result to occur.

3) My program would run and finish all calculations without any problems whatsoever. I assume this only happened when the threads behaved "ideally".

I then added the join() method after starting each thread, and this caused my program to run a bit slower, but it was, without a doubt, more consistent. I believe this is because the join() method waits for each thread to be finished before starting the next one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        SawGenerator mySawGenerator = new SawGenerator();
        mySawGenerator.start();

        try {
            mySawGenerator.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

I now feel as though I'm at a bit of an impasse as I'm trying to speed up my program. Not using join() after each thread starts is faster because it allows calculations to run side-by-side. However, it can cause errors like the ConcurrentModificationException. And in #2 of the results I found, I got an unexpected outcome where some of my code simply didn't execute.

So, I now have 2 questions:

1) What happened in #2 of the results I found when not joining my threads? Why did a whole portion of my code "skip" execution?

But more importantly:

2) How can I properly use threads in such a way that I won't get any errors as they are running? I can join each thread after they start, but that means that none of the threads can run concurrently, doesn't it? If I did this, I might as well just not use threads.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: 1000 threads is probably not a good idea if your tasks are CPU-bound. A rule of thumb for such tasks is to spawn as many threads as there are CPU cores, then do benchmarks and adjust accordingly. The trick is to load balance the work across the CPU cores evenly. Throwing more threads at the problem will just increase the overhead due to context switching. Rewrite your code so each thread takes a roughly equal chunk of work. After spawning all the threads you want to have a second loop that joins them with the main thread. Lastly, you need to use a thread safe hash map like ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question and I'm not sure whether it fits the format very well, but I'll try to answer you regardless.

> What happened in #2 of the results I found when not joining my threads? Why did a whole portion of my code "skip" execution?

When you start a thread, it is going to execute its code in the background, but the starting itself returns rather quickly. When you join a thread, you pause your own execution until the thread being joined is finished. Without joining, you are essentially sampling the execution result "as it is" in your final loop, when many threads are probably still running. Thus, you are missing those results.

> 2) How can I properly use threads in such a way that I won't get any errors as they are running? I can join each thread after they start, but that means that none of the threads can run concurrently, doesn't it? If I did this, I might as well just not use threads.

This is *way* to broad of a question, but I can give some highlights:

- Don't use more threads than you have CPU threads available for CPU-bound tasks
- Minimize concurrent modification of shared resources. Do all those threads really need to modify the Hashmap?
- Look at the producer/consumer design. You can have many threads producing your random walks and just a single one collecting finished walks.